# Is "a list" singular or plural?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

1. A list of companies  are displayed.
2. A list of companies is displayed.

Please let me know whether first or second sentence is correct.

Answer (score 4):

2. A list of companies is displayed is grammatically correct

because 'A list' clearly signifies a singular entity .

Answer (score 4):

If you put a lot of things into a bucket, it is still one bucket.  If you fill the bucket with rocks and then weight it, you would say "the bucket **is** weighed".  If you also wanted to disclose what was in the bucket at the time, you could say "the bucket of rocks **is** weighed".

If you are talking about the rocks and the bucket is irrelevant, you could say "the rocks **are** weighed", or "the rocks in the bucket **are** weighed.  In this case, it is the bucket that's the added descriptor.

The "of companies" just describes the nature of the list, but it's one list that is being displayed.  So #2, "A list of companies **is** displayed" is correct.  This describes the list, itself, being displayed:

[image]

If you want to refer directly to the companies, you could say "the companies on the list **are** displayed".  This would mean the companies that are displayed are the ones contained on the list:

[image]

<sup>*photo courtesy www.123rf.com*</sup>